# How can I pass parameter from Suitelet to Scheduled Script?

Tags: parameters, netsuite, schedule, suitescript2.0

I am trying to pass a custom parameter from my Suitelet to my Schedule Script in NetSuite SS2.0, but unsure where I am going wrong. I just get null being passed through.
I have a log which provides the correct data while parsing in the Suitelet (from the client), somewhere between passing it from Suitelet to the Scheduled script I am getting lost.

I have tried

```
var WOObjId = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name: 'custparam_wo_record'});
var WOObjId = context.request.parameters.custparam_wo_record;
```

Scheduled Script

```
define(['N/record', 'N/redirect', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/task', 'N/error', 'N/file', 'N/render', 'N/runtime', 'N/search', 'N/config'],

(record, redirect, serverWidget, task, error, file, render, runtime, search, config) => {

    /**
     * Defines the Scheduled script trigger point.
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Script execution context. Use values from the scriptContext.InvocationType enum.
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    const execute = (context) => {
                    try{
                        //Get XML File information
                            log.debug('Request Received');
                            var WOObjId = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name: 'custparam_wo_record'});
                            log.debug('object received', WOObjId)
                        //var WOObjId = [9073,9059]
                            var WOObjLength = WOObjId.length;
                            log.debug('WOObjId', WOObjId + ' length is '+ WOObjLength );
```

My Suitelet -

```
(task) => {
    /**
     * Defines the Suitelet script trigger point.
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {ServerRequest} scriptContext.request - Incoming request
     * @param {ServerResponse} scriptContext.response - Suitelet response
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    const onRequest = (context) => {
        var WOObjId = context.request.parameters.custparam_wo_record;
        log.debug('Inside Suitelet Call received', 'WO Params: ' + WOObjId);
        executeScheduled(WOObjId);
    }

    function executeScheduled(param) {
        var scriptTask = task.create({
            taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
            scriptId: "customscript_ns_ss_printwo_batchschprint",
            deploymentId: "customdeploy_ns_ss_printwo_batchschprint",
            params: {
                'custparam_wo_record' : param
            }
        });

        var scriptTaskId = scriptTask.submit();

        log.debug("scriptTaskId", scriptTaskId);
    }

    return {onRequest}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the parameter on the scheduled script's Script record. The id you set there is what you'll use for passing the parameter.

The parameter script ids are not free-form and will end up as `custscript*` e.g. `custscript_wo_record`. That is the value you'll have to pass instead of  the one prefixed by custparam.

Comment: that worked thank you! Didn't know I had to use a defined parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the parameter in the Scheduled Script record with id custparam_wo_record.
2. When calling the Scheduled make sure to pass the value in the parameter custparam_wo_record (just like you are doing). Also, make sure you are passing a text value, if it's an object you might want to use JSON.strinigfy before.
3. In the Scheduled script use the runtime module to get the parameter:
   runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name: 'custparam_wo_record'});